# Is it possible to assess Jackrabbit repository using plain HTTP?

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jsr

As I understand it should be natively available in Jackrabbit 1.6 (I've found this blog entry http://dev.day.com/microsling/content/blogs/main/jrnativehttp.html) but I can not find any example configuration.

Comment: I managed to get it working using jcr2spi http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jackrabbit-spi.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [mentioned article](http://dev.day.com/microsling/content/blogs/main/jrnativehttp.html) points out (link added):

> Anyway, to check it out run the
> [Jackrabbit 1.6 standalone server](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/jackrabbit/1.6.0/jackrabbit-standalone-1.6.0.jar) and
> find the description and some examples
> at
> http://localhost:8080/webdav-jcr.jsp

If you don't use the standalone server, you can use the Jackrabbit war distribution. The [standard web.xml](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/trunk/jackrabbit-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) is already configured to expose the JCR-over-webdav remoting at `/server`, eg.

http://localhost:8080/server

See the JCRWebdavServer servlet config in the [web.xml](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/trunk/jackrabbit-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml), using [JcrRemotingServlet](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.20/org/apache/jackrabbit/j2ee/JcrRemotingServlet.html) with batch read/write (actually implemented and documented in the [super class with the same name](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.20/org/apache/jackrabbit/server/remoting/davex/JcrRemotingServlet.html)):

```
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!-- J C R  R E M O T I N G  S E R V L E T                                  -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JCRWebdavServer</servlet-name>
    <description>
        The servlet used to remote JCR calls over HTTP.
    </description>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jackrabbit.j2ee.JcrRemotingServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>missing-auth-mapping</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
        <description>
            Defines how a missing authorization header should be handled.
            1) If this init-param is missing, a 401 response is generated.
            This is suiteable for clients (eg. webdav clients) for which
            sending a proper authorization header is not possible if the
            server never sent a 401.
            2) If this init-param is present with an empty value,
            null-credentials are returned, thus forcing an null login
            on the repository.
            3) If this init-param has a 'user:password' value, the respective
            simple credentials are generated.
        </description>
    </init-param>
    <!--
        Optional parameter to define the value of the 'WWW-Authenticate' header
    -->
    <!--
    <init-param>
        <param-name>authenticate-header</param-name>
        <param-value>Basic realm="Jackrabbit Webdav Server"</param-value>
        <description>
            Defines the value of the 'WWW-Authenticate' header.
        </description>
    </init-param>
    -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>resource-path-prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/server</param-value>
        <description>
            defines the prefix for spooling resources out of the repository.
        </description>
    </init-param>
    <!--
        Init parameters specific for JcrRemotingServlet
    -->
    <!--
    <init-param>
        <param-name>home</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
        <description>JcrRemotingServlet: Optional home directory for JcrRemotingServlet temporary files (default: "jackrabbit")</description>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>temp-directory</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
        <description>JcrRemotingServlet: Optional temporary directory name (under home, default: "tmp")</description>
    </init-param>
    -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>batchread-config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/batchread.properties</param-value>
        <description>JcrRemotingServlet: Optional mapping from node type names to default depth.</description>
    </init-param>        
    <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```